# How to find the optimized parameters in an ODE in python?

Tags: python, optimization, curve-fitting, ode, parameterization

I am trying to obtain the optimized values of 5 parameters in a differential equation with Python.
The equation is:

```
dl/dt = k1 * exp(((alpha * n * F) / (R * T)) * (V - (E * l) - phi)) - k3
```

The 5 parameters to obtain are: k1, alpha, E, phi, k3
The constants are:

```
n = 3
F = 96485
R = 8.314
T = 293
V = 0.8
```

I have the values of lengths (l) in various times (t) as experiment results. That is:

```
t = [0, 120, 360, .......]
l = [0, 0.09, 0.12, ......]
```

I also would like to assign bounds for each parameter.
Is this procedure possible in Python?
I wonder whether this should be done using scipy, platypus or any other library?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You only have 2 free parameters in `dl/dt = A-B*l`, so there is some freedom in how the 5 parameters in your formula combine to give `A` and `B`.